# why setting LINKOPTS=' ' supress error message

Tags: c, bitbake

I have a open source mdnsresponder c code which is compiled with bitbake. I don't face any issues when `LINKOPTS` is given like below

```
EXTRA_OEMAKE += "LINKOPTS=''"
```

Here nothing is set to `LINKOPTS`. So if I remove `LINKOPTS`, GCC compiler throws error message like 
`error: unrecognized command line option '--hash-style=gnu'`. Also it throws few warning messages like `-Wtype-limits, -Wunused-but-set-variable`.

Is `LINKOPTS` in this usage required ?

Answer (score 0):

Compiler provides `hashstyle=gnu` by default, so disabling it again in toplevel bitbake.